# changing theme issue in kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin

here is the button where i want to change theme when swith button is checked

```
binding.themeSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

                buttonView, isChecked
            ->
            if (isChecked) {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
                intent.putExtra("theme",true)
                saveTheme()
                displayTheme()
            }
            else{
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
            }
        })
```

here are the functions where im storing and setting the theme when checked

```
private fun saveTheme(){

        if (intent.getStringExtra("theme").toBoolean()){

            val preferences:SharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("theme", MODE_PRIVATE)

            val editor:SharedPreferences.Editor=preferences.edit()
            editor.putBoolean("theme",true)
            editor.apply()
        }
    }

    private fun displayTheme(): Boolean {

        var theme:Boolean

        var preferences:SharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("theme", MODE_PRIVATE)

        theme=preferences.getBoolean("theme",true)
        return theme

    }
```

the problem is code is not storing the preferences and not setting preferences when called

Comment: You are always putting `true` in `theme` in shared preferences. You never set `theme` back to `false` or remove the preference. That's why it always stay `true` once set.

Comment: `intent.getStringExtra("theme").toBoolean()` Can't be true

Comment: could you please sort it out programmatically